# How to implement swagger, when we are using moleculer framework for Microservices

Tags: node.js, swagger, moleculer

I am not able to find how to implement swagger when we are implementing Microservice using Moleculer framework, as i am using Api-gateway to parse and map the request and send to specific Node or service using NATS transporter.

Answer (score 1):

Check this OpenAPI mixin for API Gateway: https://github.com/icebob/kantab/blob/master/backend/mixins/openapi.mixin.js